# While reading XML commented code - exclamation mark (!) is creating an issue

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a batch file which performs text replacement operation. It is not reading commented code from XML `<!--  -->` while doing the text replacement. Hence, output file of post replacement operation with XML becomes INVALID since exclamation marks `!` were removed during operation.

Command to execute batch file:

```
batchfilename.bat "old_str" "new_str"
```

Batch file script:

```
@echo off
set "_search=%~1"
set "_replace=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
copy /y Market.xml Market_copy.xml
for /F  "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (Market.xml) DO (
    set line=%%a
    >> Market_New.xml echo(!line:%_search%=%_replace%!
)
move /y Market_New.xml Market.xml
echo Done
```

What is the reason for corrupted output on lines containing `!` and how to fix the code?

Comment: Run your batch file without `@echo off` or with modification to `@echo ON` from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking it and you see what happens on command line `set line=%%a` with loop variable `a` having assigned a line containing one or more `!` because of enabled delayed expansion resulting in parsing this line a second time and interpreting `!` as begin/end of an environment variable reference. My advice: Use [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which makes this task with one command line also for XML files.

Comment: Replace `EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of your script with `DisableDelayedExpansion`. Then after you've `Set "line=%%a"` in the `For` loop you can `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` then `>>"Market_New.xml" Echo(!line:%_search%=%_replace%!` and finally `EndLocal` before closing the loop.

Comment: Thanks Compo..it worked ! appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment, with a little improvement.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "_search=%~1"
Set "_replace=%~2"

Copy /Y "Market.xml" "Market_copy.xml"||Exit /B
(For /F  "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("Market_copy.xml") Do (Set "line=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo=!line:%_search%=%_replace%!
    EndLocal))>"Market.xml" 
Echo Done
Pause
```